# Added AD Group to SharePoint 2013, how long do I have to wait to get in?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, active-directory

How long do I have to wait to access a site if I add a AD Group I'm in to SharePoint? I believe the time can be configured through Powershell. If that is correct, then how?

Comment: The permissions should be instantaneous when you drop an AD group into SP, just like when you drop a person directly into SP. You should only see a lag when you make a change to AD itself. I don't know how to configure Powershell to do what you are suggesting, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be quick. i added a AD group into SharePoint group and its work like a charm.

But if you directly adding a AD group into SharePoint site may be take little time, I would close the browser / logout from site and re login.

only thing i know, is when you adding the groups it will cause the longer time for search crawl.

you can read about this over here. [Clarifying Guidance on SharePoint Security Groups versus Active Directory Domain Services Groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/05/06/clarifying-guidance-on-sharepoint-security-groups-versus-active-directory-domain-services-groups.aspx)

Another good article: https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/sharepoint-2013-use-ag-groups-yes-butdont-forget-the-security-token-caching-logontokencacheexpirationwindow-and-windowstokenlifetime/